# No matching function for call to 'EVP_DigestFinal' - Using openssl lib in C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have successfully integrated `openssl` dev library in `main.cpp` file. `openssl/evp.h` is currently included.

I can use `EVP_DigestInit`, `EVP_DigestUpdate` functions successfully without any error. But if I try to call `EVP_DigestFinal`, it gives following error:

```
No matching function for call to 'EVP_DigestFinal'
```

Whereas, the functions are defined in the same header file, `evp.h`. What should I do in order to use this function too?  Thanks for help.

Related code:

```
EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
char ch[128];
int val = 128;
EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, ch, val);
```

Comment: did you include the ssl library with the makefile?

Comment: I develop with xcode. I have included necessary libraries. If I try to write in C, there is no problem. When I try with c++ file, it gives this error. There should be another problem, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I find at [OpenSSL.org](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html), the signature is

```
int EVP_DigestFinal(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *md, int *s);
```

To match that you need `unsigned char` for the second parameter and an address for the third parameter, something like

```
EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
unsigned char ch[128];
_______^
int val = 128;
EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, ch, &val);
__________________________^
```

Comment: I've just mistyped here in question part. My code is as you write above. This doesn't affect the situation.

Comment: When I did necessary corrections together with using `val` as `unsigned int`, it has worked.